# Using C#, how do I get all rows from smartsheet where "x" is in column 2?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I need to get all rows from a single Smartsheet sheet, which contain an "x" in column 2.
I am using C# to complete this.

Comment: You should read [ask] and improve and add code to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to find any code when I first posted this. As such, I had no code to post. I kept the question to the point, but it says exactly what I am requiring. Please give me more helpful critique as to what could be added to improve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code I managed to find after a little more searching:

```
 public void GetJobNoOfAllProjects(SmartsheetClient smartsheet, long sheetId, out List<string> matches)
{
    jobNoMatches = new List<string>();
    Sheet sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            
    foreach (Row tmpRow in sheet.Rows)
    {
        if (tmpRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "PROJECT")
        {
            //Do what is required to the row
            jobNoMatches.Add(tmpRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Needs error handling in case it comes across a blank cell, but that's what I came up with.

ALTERNATIVELY

```
 public void GetJobNoOfAllProjects(SmartsheetClient smartsheet, long sheetId, out List<string> matches)
{
    jobNoMatches = new List<string>();
    Sheet sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    int loop = 0;
    while (loop < sheet.Rows.Count)
    {
        if (sheet.Rows[loop].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "PROJECT")
        {
            //Do what is required to the row
            jobNoMatches.Add(sheet.Rows[loop].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
        loop++;
    }
}
```